# Car driving experience not smooth

Tags: engine, nissan

My Nissan Altima 2002 (106873 miles). It used to smooth after oil changes. But, I have been noticing that the car is not smooth as it used to be after oil changes. It used to feel like the car was flowing like water now it feel like I'm driving a cart (not exactly). But, what I can I do to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What isn't smooth? Is it at a certain speed? When turning? When going over rough terrain? What? Also, I highly doubt you can notice any change in engine smoothness after an oil change--save for the placebo effect.

Answer (score 2):

Getting an oil change should not make your car go from driving like crap to all of a sudden brand new, there are a lot of other maintaince that must go into a car other than simply doing an oil change.  When you get your oil changed do you also have them check the transmission fluid, differential fluid, power steering fluid...also your using the word smooth, whats not smooth about it, without that info we can only assume your car is simply not maintained well, with over 100000 its prolly time for new brake rotors, shocks, a complete flush of all system fluids including brake fluids, has any of this been done?